# Facebook, Twitter and Google login example in Rails/Django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, facebook

Iam looking for a Django or Rails example with Google login+Facebook+Twitter. My goal is to develop something like Nerddinner.com...The example should be updated (most of the examples I found was outdated) and working. Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean an app like [django-social-auth](http://social.matiasaguirre.net/)?

Check [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/) to find more.

Answer (score 1):

check out [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for rails. it uses omniauth for such purposes and it's very well documented, you shouldn't have any problems with it